# Mathematica cannot solve this complicated integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, mathematica-online

first-time here. I am trying to use Mathematica to evaluate a solution from Duhamel's principle, the integration looks like

$\int^t_0\frac{e^{-ks-\frac{r^2}{2(2Ds+\sigma^2+2D_pt)}}}{2Ds+\sigma^2+2D_pt}ds$

Mathematica gives output of "This computation has exceeded the time limit for your plan". I wonder if this integral is just too much for it, or is there another way thats worth trying. I'm using the online version. Thanks!

-----Edit-----

The original codes I used were:

```
L2 = 2 * D * s + 2 Dp*t + sigma^2

eqn = 1/L2*Exp[-k * s]*Exp[-r^2/(2 *L2)]

Integrate[eqn, {s, 0, t}]
```

Comment: I realize how much effort you put into making your equation into the form you could publish in a book. Could you edit your post to include the plane ordinary no-subscripts Mathematica code that you used? That would let others avoid having to decompile your formatted code back to Mathematica so they could try things and avoid any mistakes and misunderstandings they might have in the process. Thanks

Comment: Fixed, thanks for your comment

Comment: Desktop MMA v. 13.3 gives up on your integral, returning the input. There may not be a closed form solution, or MMA may not know of it. You could try [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org/) to get an antiderivative, but an analytic answer may just not exist.

Comment: Not every integral has a closed form, but you can still perform the integral numerically if you know the values of your parameters.

Answer (score 3):

This integral can be expressed by [Leaky Aquifer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.12186.pdf) function or  Generalization of the Incomplete Gamma function.

Let's consider:

```
S = MellinTransform[
E^(-k  x - (X*r^2)/(2 (2 dp t + 2 d x + \[Sigma]^2)))/(
2 dp t + 2 d x + \[Sigma]^2), X, q] // PowerExpand // 
FullSimplify(*Where: X=1*)
(*2^q E^(-k x) r^(-2 q) (2 dp t + 2 d x + \[Sigma]^2)^(-1 + q) Gamma[q]*)

INT = Integrate[S, {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t > 0, 
GenerateConditions -> False] // Simplify // FunctionExpand // 
Expand // PowerExpand
(*2^(-1 + 2 q) d^(-1 + q) E^((k (2 dp t + \[Sigma]^2))/(2 d))
 k^-q r^(-2 q) Gamma[q] Gamma[q, (k (2 dp t + \[Sigma]^2))/(2 d)] - 
2^(-1 + 2 q) d^(-1 + q) E^((k (2 dp t + \[Sigma]^2))/(2 d))
k^-q r^(-2 q)
Gamma[q] Gamma[q, (k (2 (d + dp) t + \[Sigma]^2))/(2 d)]*)

InverseMellinTransform[INT, q, X] /. X -> 1(*Can't find!*)

(*E^((k (2 dp t + \[Sigma]^2))/(2 d))
InverseMellinTransform[
1/2  ((4 d)/(k r^2))^
q  Gamma[q]  Gamma[q, (k (2 dp t + \[Sigma]^2))/(2 d)], q, 1] - 
 E^((k (2 dp t + \[Sigma]^2))/(2 d))
 InverseMellinTransform[
 1/2  ((4 d)/(k r^2))^
 q  Gamma[q]  Gamma[q, (k (2 (d + dp) t + \[Sigma]^2))/(2 d)], q,1]*)
```

And using Table formula of Inverse Mellin Transform:

$$\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[a^{-q} \Gamma (q) \Gamma (q,b)\right](x)=K\left[0,b,\frac{a x}{b}\right]$$

where: $K\left[0,b,\frac{a x}{b}\right]$ is Leaky Aquifer function.

we have:

```
1/2  E^((k (2 dp t + \[Sigma]^2))/(
2 d))  (K[0, (k (2 dp t + \[Sigma]^2))/(2 d), r^2/(
4 dp t + 2 \[Sigma]^2)] - 
K[0, (k (2 (d + dp) t + \[Sigma]^2))/(2 d), r^2/(
4 (d + dp) t + 2 \[Sigma]^2)]
```

$$\int_0^t \frac{e^{-k x-\frac{r^2}{2 \left(2 \text{dp} t+2 d x+\sigma ^2\right)}}}{2 \text{dp} t+2 d x+\sigma ^2} \, dx=\\\frac{1}{2}
   e^{\frac{k \left(2 \text{dp} t+\sigma ^2\right)}{2 d}} \left(K\left[0,\frac{k \left(2 \text{dp} t+\sigma ^2\right)}{2
   d},\frac{r^2}{4 \text{dp} t+2 \sigma ^2}\right]-K\left[0,\frac{k \left(2 (d+\text{dp}) t+\sigma ^2\right)}{2 d},\frac{r^2}{4
   (d+\text{dp}) t+2 \sigma ^2}\right]\right)$$

For general $v$ Inverse Mellin Transform:

$$\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}[E_{1-q+v}(x) \Gamma (q)](y)=\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[x^{-q+v} \Gamma (q) \Gamma (q-v,x)\right](y)=K[v,x,y]$$

where: $E_{-q+v+1}(x)$ is the exponential integral function and $K[v,x,y]$ is Leaky Aquifer function.

Answer (score 0):

There is one issue, capital "D" is differentiate. As a rule, avoid single capital letters as symbols in Mathematica (C, D, E, I, N).

```
     L2 = 2*d*s + 2 dp*t + \[Sigma] ^2
     eqn = 1/L2*Exp[-k*s]*Exp[-r^2/(2*L2)]
    Integrate[eqn, {s, 0, t}]

    LaplaceTransform[Exp[-r^2/(a s +b)]/(a s +b), s,k]
```

both no results.

But

```
   1/(2 r) D[  E^(-(r^2/(a s + b))), r]
```

$$-\frac{e^{-\frac{r^2}{a s+b}}}{a s+b}$$

```
      1/(2 r) D[Integrate[  E^(-(r^2/(a s + b))), s], r]

       ExpIntegralEi[-(r^2/(b + a s))]/a
```

Proof

```
    D[ExpIntegralEi[-(r^2/(b + a s))]/a, s]
```

$$-\frac{e^{-\frac{r^2}{a s+b}}}{a s+b}$$